# node.js parsing html text to get a value to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I' doing this successfully to get the help text of my page of interest.

```
router.get('/get', function (req, res) {
    var pg = 'https://j......com/f/resource'
    console.log('get', pg);
    requestify.get(pg).then(function (resp) {
        console.log(resp.body);
    });
});
```

Now that I have the page's text, I'm wanting to parse the text to get the value of a javascript variable which I know exists in the text.

```
<script> var x1 = {"p": {.......bla bla ...}};</script>
```

I know that sometimes the `<script>` tag will include the type attribute; but it will not always include the type attribute.

When I find the value of `x1` I what to use that in my javascript's app's as a value in `myVar` variable.

If you do not have THE answer then your comment/tip as to what I should research is appreciated.

I was hoping I would find some module I can just drop the entire text into and have the module somehow just output all variables a values for me.

Comment: You may want to avoid the parsing aspect and try something "direct" like [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), where you can load (and execute) the page then grab the resulting value. Assuing it's as written, it should be easy to grab `window.x1` since you're not competing with funky closures.

Comment: I'll have a look.  Thanks for the tip.  Sounds like the kind of thing I was hoping for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're not re-inventing the wheel, I feel like using [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) (and it's execution capabilities) would be the best best. To mock what you have:

```
const express   = require('express');
const jsdom     = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom; // it exports a JSDOM class

// Mock a remote resource
const remote = express()
  .use('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Test document</title><script>var x1 = { "p": { "foo": "bar" } };</script></head><body></body></html>');
  })
  .listen(3001);

// Create "your" server
const local = express()
  .use('/', (req, res) => {
    // fetch the remote resource and load it into JSDOM. No need for
    // requestify, but you can use the JSDOM ctor and pass it a string
    // if you're doing something more complex than hitting an endpoint
    // (like passing auth, creds, etc.)
    JSDOM.fromURL('http://localhost:3001/', {
      runScripts: "dangerously" // allow <script> to run
    }).then((dom) => {
      // pass back the result of "x1" from the context of the
      // loaded dom page.
      res.send(dom.window.x1);
    });
  })
  .listen(3000);
```

I then receive back:

```
{"p":{"foo":"bar"}}
```

Comment: Oh Wow!  Worked AND So Simple.  A rare combination to find = awesome.

Comment: Indeed. Brief and concise are sometimes hard to come by, but luckily there are still great library authors out there with clean APIs.